# How to sort an Array with Dictionaries which include date?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, date

In my `Swift`project there is an `Array` with `Dictionaries`. Each `Dictionary`contains a `String` of `date`. How can I get a new `Array`with `date`from newest to oldest? Thanks!

```
var array = [["date":"2016-02-12","title":"1"],["date":"2014-05-12","title":"2"],["date":"2016-06-18","title":"3"],["date":"2015-09-17","title":"4"]]
```

Comment: Uh, by using the `sorted` method with an appropriate sorting closure? Is this a trick question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
let array2 = array.sorted {$0["date"]! < $1["date"]!}
```

Comment: Thanks matt, I am working on a project at work and this helps solve my problem. Don't understand why people give me "-".

Comment: Might be because this kind of problem is easy to solve if (1) you learn Swift, or (2) you search Stack Overflow, where this has been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: Thanks matt, I did do some research but didn't find an answer can solve my problem exactly. Anyway, will do more research in the future. Happy Friday!